# Could Not Find Installable ISAM Excel 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel, excel-2010

I have this sub in Excel 2010 that's supposed to copy in a table from Access 2010. When I try to run the code, it gives me a 'Could not find installable ISAM'. When I debug, it highlights objDB.Execute.

```
Private Sub btnGetData_Click()

Unload ParameterMenu
formWait.Show

'Save workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Save

Dim strExcelFile As String
Dim strWorksheet As String
Dim strDB As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim objDB As Database

strExcelFile = "X:\Form.xlsm"
strWorksheet = "RawDates"
strDB = "X:\Tables.accdb"
strTable = "Dates"

Set objDB = OpenDatabase(strDB)

objDB.Execute _ 'Error occurs here.
  "SELECT * INTO [Excel 14.0;DATABASE=" & strExcelFile & _
   "].[" & strWorksheet & "] FROM " & "[" & strTable & "]"

objDB.Close
Set objDB = Nothing

Unload formWait
FinishDialog.Show

End Sub
```

I'm not overly experienced with VBA, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format is 'Excel 12.0 Macro' rather than 'Excel 14.0':

```
objDB.Execute _ 'Error occurs here.
  "SELECT * INTO [Excel 12.0 Macro;DATABASE=" & strExcelFile & _
   "].[" & strWorksheet & "] FROM " & "[" & strTable & "]"
```

Edit:

Perhaps try ADO instead:

```
Private Sub btnGetData_Click()

Unload ParameterMenu
formWait.Show

'Save workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Save

Dim strExcelFile As String
Dim strWorksheet As String
Dim strDB As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim objDB As Object
Dim rs As Object

strExcelFile = "X:\Form.xlsm"
strWorksheet = "RawDates"
strDB = "X:\Tables.accdb"
strTable = "Dates"

Set objDB = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With objDB
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
      .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & strDB & ";"
      .Open
   End With

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM " & "[" & strTable & "]", objDB, 3, 1, 1

If Not rs.EOF Then _
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strWorksheet).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
objDB.Close
Set objDB = Nothing

Unload formWait
FinishDialog.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: It's now giving me an error 3011, saying it can't find RawDates. I've double checked all the names and they are correct, however it keeps giving me this error.

Comment: If it's an existing sheet, you need to use `RawDates$` as the name.

Comment: Are you trying to append to an existing sheet or create a new one?

Comment: Append. The table already exists and I want to add data to it. But even when I delete the table, it gives me the 3011 error.

Comment: Are you writing to the same workbook the code is in? For an append query you want an INSERT INTO rather than SELECT INTO - something like: `"INSERT INTO [Excel 12.0 Macro;DATABASE=" & strExcelFile & _
   "].[" & strWorksheet & "] SELECT * FROM " & "[" & strTable & "]"`

Comment: Yes, I am. I did this, but now it's giving me an error 3823 telling me that the ability to edit data in a linked excel sheet is disabled in this access release. I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: I've added an alternative method - can you try that?

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly without any problem! Thank you so much, you are wonderful.